# Creating a type based on a JSON file's keys

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create a type from an imported json module's content?

i.e.

```
import * as config from './config.json'
```

config.json

```
{
    "known_value": {
        "unknown_key": "value",
        "unknown_key2": "value2",
    }
}
```

I tried

```
type functions = keyof config.known_value;
```

hoping to produce:

```
type functions = 'unknown_key' | 'unknown_key2';
```

Comment: [Import assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#import-assertions) feature might be helpful in your case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**

I actually misread the question, you didn't simply miss one step, you were missing the `typeof` concept, which can be used to extract the type from a value.

---

You are simply missing the last step, to extract the keys of `known_value`

```js
type Keys = keyof typeof config.known_value
```